How to make Tk widgets flow from left to right and then top to bottom?
I have to display dozens of radio buttons (grouped by three) in a frame and would like them to flow like text: from left to right and when the line is full, create a second line below.
How would you do this?
EDIT: after some nice comments I got this:
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Elementario')
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

text = tkinter.Text(root, wrap=tkinter.WORD)
text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH)

modules = [
    {'name':'reset_display'},
    {'name':'number_to_bin_str'},
    {'name':'number_to_dec_str'},
    {'name':'number_to_hex_str'},
    {'name':'list_to_number'},
    {'name':'list_to_bin_str'},
    {'name':'list_to_dec_str'}]

mod_vars = {}

for mod in modules:
    name = mod['name']
    rb_frame = tkinter.Frame(text)
    rb_frame.pack()
    label = tkinter.Label(rb_frame, text=name)
    label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    mod_vars[name] = tkinter.StringVar(value="0")
    rb_T = tkinter.Radiobutton(rb_frame, text="T",
            variable=mod_vars[name], value="T",)
    rb_T.grid(row=0, column=2)
    rb_U = tkinter.Radiobutton(rb_frame, text="U",
            variable=mod_vars[name], value="U")
    rb_U.grid(row=0, column=3)

root.mainloop()

The radio buttons are centered in the text widget and I could not find a way to make them flow from left to right then top to bottom.

By hand.  There's no automatic packing that does this.  You can find the width of the text and track the position yourself.

Wao, the great Tim Roberts! Then I guess there's really no other way than by hand!!!

Use a Text widget to store those radio buttons and set wrap on.

I second using a Text widget.  The only fiddly part is if you want neat rows and columns then you have to give the embedded widgets an explicit size.

No need for neat columns but OK I'll set explicit height if needed. It doesn't work yet, do I have to separate the widgets with a space? If so, how do I do it?

We cannot identify your issue without seeing the code.  It is better to provide a [mre].

You need to use text.window_create("end", window=rb_frame) instead of rb_frame.pack() to put the frame into the text widget.

You need to use text.window_create("end", window=rb_frame) to put those frames into the text widget.
Below is the modified code:
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Elementario')
#root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.geometry("600x300") # use smaller window to show the effect

text = tkinter.Text(root, wrap=tkinter.WORD)
text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

modules = [
    {'name':'reset_display'},
    {'name':'number_to_bin_str'},
    {'name':'number_to_dec_str'},
    {'name':'number_to_hex_str'},
    {'name':'list_to_number'},
    {'name':'list_to_bin_str'},
    {'name':'list_to_dec_str'}]

mod_vars = {}

for mod in modules:
    name = mod['name']
    # give the frame a border to show the effect easier
    rb_frame = tkinter.Frame(text, bd=1, relief="solid", bg="white")
    #rb_frame.pack()
    label = tkinter.Label(rb_frame, text=f"{name}:")
    label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    mod_vars[name] = tkinter.StringVar(value="0")
    rb_T = tkinter.Radiobutton(rb_frame, text="T",
            variable=mod_vars[name], value="T",)
    rb_T.grid(row=0, column=2)
    rb_U = tkinter.Radiobutton(rb_frame, text="U",
            variable=mod_vars[name], value="U")
    rb_U.grid(row=0, column=3)

    # put the frame into the text widget
    text.window_create("end", window=rb_frame, padx=1, pady=1)

root.mainloop()

Result:

